# Caching public JWT authentication keys in Azure Function

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having an Azure function .NET core 2.1 with various endpoints.

For Authentication I'm having an external security provider from where I need to retrieve the discovery document (metadata) before being able to validate a request's token.

The document is currently getting loaded every time a single request is made:

```cs
var discoveryDocument = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
```

Now I naturally don't want to make this call for every single request due to the fact that the document changes rarely.

On the other hand Azure functions are stateless. I heard of `ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()` is caching the retrieved data somehow, though I couldn't find more information on this. Currently I ended up with a function which gets triggered on startup once, retrieves the document and stores it in the local filesystem. So when a request is made, I'm reading the file again just to avoid another request for getting the public keys.

Any experience on this?

## Solution:

I could solve it with a static class as @juunas suggested.
For every single function I am re-using the `ValidateToken()` method. The call for the discovery document is made every once in a while (when `IConfigurationManager` thinks it needs to be refreshed) because it is getting cached automatically.

```cs
class AuthConfig
{
    static readonly IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> _configurationManager;

    static AuthConfig()
    {
        _configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
            "<CONFIGURL>",
            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
            new HttpDocumentRetriever());
    }

    public static async Task<MyUserEntity> ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        var discoveryDocument = await _configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKeys = discoveryDocument.SigningKeys,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = discoveryDocument.Issuer
        };

        try
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var rawValidatedToken);
            var user = ParseMyUserEntity(claimsPrincipal);
            return user;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, could you maybe use a static field to hold it?

Comment: That would solve it for only one particular endpoint, not in general, right? I would need a static IConfigurationManager for every function or am I wrong?

Comment: Or a static class with a static field. It depends how the runtime runs the functions, which I'm not super familiar with :/

Comment: Working! Thanks @juunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data in a static field (which can be in a separate static class too).

That should work as an in-memory cache on that function instance at least.
If the function gets scaled to multiple instances, their caches will be separated.